# fancybox iframe auto resize

Tags: jquery, fancybox

is it possible to set the width and height to auto in a fancybox iframe?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. You can, however, do the following:

On iframe resize, pass its new dimensions to a function within its parent that adjusts the fancybox accordingly. Will only work if parent & iframe share the same domain due to security restrictions.

Comment: It also appears that `parent.$.fancybox.resize()` doesn't work for iframes either.

Comment: Technically, it works -- it's just that the iframe itself keeps its preset height, so there's no change to adapt to. You will need to explicitly resize that iframe to it's inner dimensions and then call fb's resize method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click a link it opens in the same box and resize it so I did:

Inside the box I put the main content + the main link that will open the User, when clicking on the link instead of opening the address he only do a $ ('#main').hide(); and $('#secundary').show();

For me it was sufficient ;)

```
$(function() {

   $('.link').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $('#main').hide();
     $('#secundary').show();
   });

});
```